# Error installing the R package: CBNplot on github

Tags: r, package

I want to install the CBNplot package on GitHub:
Making the website：https://github.com/noriakis/CBNplot
Try two methods:
The first is direct download：
The following error occurs：

```
devtools::install_github("noriakis/CBNplot")
```

---

Installing package into ‘C:/Users/sjadsqf/Documents/R/win-library/4.1’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

- installing *source* package 'CBNplot' ...
  ** using staged installation
  ** R
  ** data
  ** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
  Error: object 'choose.direction' is not exported by 'namespace:bnlearn'
  Execution halted
  ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'CBNplot'
- removing 'C:/Users/sjadsqf/Documents/R/win-library/4.1/CBNplot'
  Warning message:
  In i.p(...) :
  installation of package ‘C:/Users/sjadsqf/AppData/Local/Temp/RtmpMHHiTR/file555833c63074/CBNplot_0.99.2.tar.gz’ had non-zero exit status

---

Then I tried the second method

```
pkgbuild::build("D:/R/CBNplot-main",
            dest_path = "D:/R/library/")
```

---

Error: object 'choose.direction' is not exported by 'namespace:bnlearn'
Execution halted
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'CBNplot'

- removing 'C:/Users/sjadsqf/AppData/Local/Temp/Rtmp2F15K6/Rinst5c845a222d2f/CBNplot'
  -----------------------------------
  ERROR: package installation failed
  Error in `(function (command = NULL, args = character(), error_on_status = TRUE, ...`:
  ! System command 'Rcmd.exe' failed

---

### Exit status: 1
stdout & stderr:

---

i notice that error
Error: object 'choose.direction' is not exported by 'namespace:bnlearn'

So I tried to install belearn，After the installation is complete, the above error still appears in the operation

Answer (score 0):

If you look at the [changelog](https://github.com/cran/bnlearn/blob/e4617fe5d6361d00de6cdd1c4058c09bb22820d5/Changelog) for the package `bnlearn`, it says

> Version 4.8
>
> - ...
> - removed choose.direction().

The lastest version of bnlearn therefore does not have the `choose.direction` function that the earlier versions had. Obviously, the CBNplot package uses this function, so the update in bnlearn has effectively broken the existing version of CBNplot.

The solution is to install an earlier version of `bnlearn`. For example, if I do

```r
remove.packages('bnlearn')
devtools::install_version('bnlearn', version = '4.7')
devtools::install_github("noriakis/CBNplot")
```

and skip any package updates that are offered, I can install the package without difficulties.

Comment: Thank you very much. According to what you said, I have successfully solved the problem